# private method of superclass executes on subclass reference

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, static

Given the following code:

**SuperClass :**

```
package poc.poc;

public class SuperClass {

    private void method() {
    System.out.println("SuperClass!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SuperClass s = new SubClass();
    s.method();
    }

}
```

**SubClass :**

```
package poc.poc;

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public void method() {
    System.out.println("Subclass!");
    }
}
```

When I run the main method of `SuperClass` , I would expect to get an exception of some sort, but actually the code in the `SuperClass` is run, rather than the code in the `SubClass`, and therefore running an instance method of the superclass type on a subclass instance.

Why does this happen?
EDIT: Doesn't this violate encapsulation?

P.S. When changing to protected rather than private modifier, polymorphism starts to kick in and we're back to something I would call "expected behavior"

Comment: That's because the private method is in scope since you're in the same file. If you create that `main` in a third file your code won't compile.

Comment: Put a `@Override` annotation on SubClass' `method` and you will understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A private method cannot be overrided, that alone explains what you see here. You are able to call the method in your main because the main is in the same class, otherwise it would not be possible.

You correctly analyzed what happens when changing `private` to `protected` : the method is now overridable and the "nearest" definition of it is executed when calling it on a subclass instance.

Comment: How could a subclass actually be able to run code from the private part of a superclass, doesn't this violate the principle of encapsulation?

Comment: and what if the private method would call overridable methods? What would happen then?

Comment: That is not what happens, since you were able to do this only from the main method of the same class. You could not do it from anywhere else, so there is no encapsulation issue

Comment: @VladIlie It would not be different, I can show you an example of how it can be useful if you want

Comment: but would the SuperClass methods be called, or the SubClass overriden methods?

Comment: Haha let me think, the example I was thinking about is not as good as I thought

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64087/discussion-between-vlad-ilie-and-dici).

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to override a private method. Instead, the subclass is **hiding** it. That means that when the subclass is used polymorphically, the method is not considered one of the parent's existing methods. It's like a whole new method that's not available through polymorphism.

The private method is not part of the parent's class contract. Polymorphism only applies to methods that are part of the parent's contract. If it wasn't like that, you could cause a class to act differently than its contract, by changing implementation where the author wanted it to be private. If the author wanted you to do that, they would have used `protected` instead. In effect, a `private` method is like `final`.

In this particular main method, because it is defined in the actual parent's class, it is able to see a private method and therefore able to call it. If your main method has been in any other class and tried to call it, it would have failed.